# How to Install Windows Alongside Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, windows-8, 14.04, system-installation

I have a computer which is currently running Ubuntu 14.04. I would like to dual boot with Windows 8. I can not find any instructions for installing Windows after Ubuntu is already installed. I am only finding instructions for doing the opposite, Installing Ubuntu after Windows 8.

Answer (score 2):

Installing Windows after Ubuntu is easy.  Just Install it as you normally would.  Windows give you the option of choosing the partition where you want to install it.  Choose the partition that has sufficient space and run your install.

After you do this it will boot to Windows.  You won't see Ubuntu.  You'll have to run a grub update procedure to get Ubuntu to boot again.

This isn't as complicated as it might seem.  The official ubuntu support site has the procedure here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

While there are other boot managers I prefer Grub.  So I would recommend reinstalling grub after you install Windows.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use GParted to divide the partitions.
2. Then install Windows on that new partition, so Windows won't take over Ubuntu partition.
3. After that, boot with portable Ubuntu CD or pendrive, install Grub bootloader, so you can see back your Ubuntu.

:)