# make bootable hard disk to install multiple OS

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I have two partitions in my hard drive. So I want to install Windows in one of my partitions and keep Ubuntu on the other. To do so, I want to use my external hard drive to boot and install Windows 7 then to boot using Ubuntu to restore Grub. The point here is that I need my External hard drive to allow me to boot using multiple operating systems. I created a partition on it and tried to use YUMI to add a Windows 7 iso and Ubuntu iso. But when I restart the PC, only Ubuntu is showing on the list !

Please tell me how can I achieve my goal. Thanks

**Edit**

What I want is to make my external hard drive like an installation CD for multiple systems ( particularly Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 7)

Comment: Why do you need to install anything on an external hard drive when you ultimately want both operating systems on the same (internal) disk?

Comment: I don't want to install them on the external disk, I just want to use the external like a CD of installation for both systems

Comment: Ok, that wasn't clear to me from the question. Perhaps you should [edit] it to clarify for other readers.

Comment: Added an edit to the question

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Install Windows Alongside Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/456629/how-to-install-windows-alongside-ubuntu)

Comment: I was able to do this with a Windows 7 repair disk and several Ubuntu ISO. I first created NTFS partition and make flash drive bootable as Windows repair. I then installed grub to MBR, and made sure that it did not create /boot that was not the same as /Boot. With NTFS you cannot bave both, but Linux sees them differently. So in /Boot I had the Windows BCD and grub folder. I added my own chain load entry to the sda1 partition to boot Windows. Then I added the ext4 partition, copied many ISO into it and added each to my manually configured grub.cfg.

Comment: @oldfred This is what I want to do, but I have no experience with theses tasks. Is there any tool which can do this automatically or can you give more details ? (for exemple, how to make the flash bootable as Windows, and what is the syntax of the grub.cfg file )

Comment: I was not able to create a Windows repair flash drive from Ubuntu, so I created the DVD and used Windows commands while booted in DVD to format, copy DVD to flash drive and make flash drive bootable. Do not remember details. Confirmed it would boot Windows, but repairCD was tiny and flash drive had lots of room. So I used gparted to shrink Windows partition and made a anaother partition for the ISO. Not sure if it would work with full install or not. The ISO boot is here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/388382/multi-partition-multi-os-bootable-usb/388484#388484