# how to run windows 8 along with ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-8, windows-10

i have a dell Inspiron 3542 with 1TB space. Ubuntu 12.04 LTS is already installed in it. I want to install windows 8 or if possible windows 10 too. is it possible to dual boot? I'm new to Ubuntu and don't know much about dual boot. could u please tell me how to run windows 8 on an Ubuntu desktop?

Comment: This question has already been asked [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/456629/how-to-install-windows-alongside-ubuntu)

Comment: You may also need instructions on [how to create a Windows bootable USB stick with Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-with-ubuntu). These answers work for me.

Comment: If older BIOS, not newer UEFI, you must have a primary NTFS formatted partition with the boot flag. Or unallocated space to create primary partitions. If you have used all the primary partitions, you cannot install it.

Answer (score 0):

Just install Windows 10 from a bootable drive as usual and make sure to install it in a different partition than the one in which Ubuntu is on.