# Installing Windows 10 in dual boot with Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, windows

I have Ubuntu 16.04 running on my machine, but for some purposes I need to install Windows. I like Ubuntu, however, and I wanna use it as my prior OS. So what I want to find out how to do is - how to install Windows 10 in dual boot os whilist keeping my Ubuntu 16.04 and how to ensure that Ubuntu is the default boot option? Also, is it than possible to make them each get access to only part of my hard drive? I got only one hard drive and I want each of them to use seperate disk part and not overlap.

So how do I do this all?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Install Windows Alongside Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/456629/how-to-install-windows-alongside-ubuntu)

Comment: have you considered virtualization?

Comment: No virtualization cause than I wouldn't be capable to run several GPU-intense programs such as Unreal Engine 4(and it's game exports) and some games.

Comment: I would caution against it. The upgrade from Windows 7 to Windows 10 (on a dual boot computer) zapped both my Windows and Ubuntu partitions making the computer unusable. In theory that should not happen. The recommended approach is to install Windows first, then install Ubuntu. Please read this Ask Ubuntu post: How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu? http://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

i noticed the forum and your question. I know you can partition the hard drive with some software that will enable you to have two separate partitions on one hard drive for two separate systems. I believe when doing a duel boot there isn't really a Default boot option however i may be wrong.
An example of some software free to download and use to partition your hard drive is: Gparted, i've used this software myself it worked like a charm. Pretty easy to use the two links below are the download link for the software and a web page of how to use it. Hope this helped!! :)
Download: http://gparted.org/download.php
Help page: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/gparted-ultimate-partitioning-software/